# How to add custom fields into October CMS static pages plugin?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, octobercms

I want to add custom field "thumbnail" into menu form in static pages plugin.

I already add this field into project/plugins/rainlab/pages/classes/menuitem/fields.yaml

```
# ===================================
#  Field Definitions
# ===================================

fields:

    title:
        span: left
        label: rainlab.pages::lang.menuitem.title

    type:
        span: right
        label: rainlab.pages::lang.menuitem.type
        type: dropdown

    url:
        label: rainlab.pages::lang.menuitem.url

    reference:
        label: rainlab.pages::lang.menuitem.reference
        type: dropdown
        cssClass: input-sidebar-control

    thumbnail:
        label: Thumbnail
        mode: file
        cssClass: input-sidebar-control
        type: mediafinder

// another part of code is default
```

Also add in project/plugins/rainlab/pages/classes/MenuItem.php

```
public $thumbnail;

public $fillable = [
    'title',
    'nesting',
    'type',
    'url',
    'code',
    'reference',
    'cmsPage',
    'replace',
    'viewBag',
    'thumbnail' // new field
];
```

But it doesn't works. How to solve this problem? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For simple type of field also need change js file

```
plugins/rainlab/pages/formwidgets/menuitems/assets/js/menu-items-editor.js
```

in function

```
MenuItemsEditor.prototype.applyMenuItem
```

change **basicProperties**

example

```
basicProperties = {
            'title': 1,
            'type': 1,
            'code': 1,
            'thumbnail': 1
        },
```

But for file it not work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to extend the Plugin, more info in the docs: https://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/extending#extending-backend-form